# Jupyter-view (from itkwidgets): Error displaying widget: model not found

Tags: view, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to install jupyter-itkwidgets extension but can't make it work in a JupyterLab.
Once installed and executed the following cells:

import vtk
import itk
from itkwidgets import view

viewer = view(data_3D, ui_collapsed=True)
viewer.interpolation = False

viewer

I get the following error message: "Error displaying widget: model not found"

I have already verified that:

- Jupyter widgets are enabled: jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension (Validating: ok)
- Updated itkwidgets: pip install itkwidgets --upgrade
- ipywidgets version: 7.8.1

Comment: You seem to mention Jupyter a lot and presumably you are using a Python-based kernel. 'Python' would probably be a better topic tag than 'view'.  For pasting code in so it is readable in forums such as this, you'll want to learn about 'fenced code blocks' [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/8508004). (Or see about 'block code formatting' [here](https://meta.discourse.org/t/post-code-or-preformatted-text/188910#block-code-formatting-6). They are both the same thing if you look into the details. They just have slightly different terms used in the two locations.) ...

Comment: As to your issue, I'm not convinced you are using the right tech for this. Jupyterview [here](https://github.com/trungleduc/jupyterview) says it is only compatible with **JupyterLab** 3 and above (4.1 is the most current release). The reason for saying that is you mention, "Jupyter widgets are enabled: jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension (Validating: ok)". That is the nbextension system for Jupyter Notebook 6.4 and earlier or NbClassic. Those don't work with JupyterView according to what I just pointed out. ...

Comment: <continued> Similarly [here at the itkwidgets](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/itkwidgets) page it mentions Jupyter Notebook but nothing about nbextension enabling. That is because Jupyter Notebook 7 which is current, doesn't use nbextensions anymore as Jupyter Notebook 7+ is built on top of JupyterLab tech. Maybe more importantly for all this is that both these tools work with JupyterLite and offer demos that will run on your system now in your browser using WebAssembly without you needing to install anything. You should treat the JupyterLite session like a remote computer ...

Comment: <caution> and upload the input data you want. And save anything useful you make back out onto your proper file system on your local computer. Word of caution: The file system in the file navigation of JupyterLite is more like a virtual one running inside your browser using WebAssembly and so it doesn't really have access to you local system because of current security and getting things out later is not really an option. In short what yo put in is only as persistent as your browser's internal stuff and so if clear the cache or things, then *poof* it is gone.

Comment: Alternatively, to have a full Python kernel where these tools work: If you go to [the Jupyterview](https://github.com/trungleduc/jupyterview) repo, you'll see the 'launch binder' badge you can click on to launch a temporary Jupyter session served by the MyBinder service on remote virtual computer. (The MyBinder service is the same one the Jupyter developers use to share a lot of the examples of the Jupyter ecosystem. Some of the more popular ones have been replaced with using JupyterLite to cut down on stress to the MyBinder resources.) ...

Comment: <continued>  I know that itkwidgets also had a mybinder offering at one point. I don't see it highlighted on the main repo now but [here](https://discourse.itk.org/t/links-on-pypi-for-itkwidgets-need-update/5273) has links that still work to launch a session. Oh wait [here](https://itkwidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployments.html#jupyter-notebook) it is in the documentation where they want to use itkwidgets with mybinder. **Importantly, these tools will be all set up and working in the appropriate sessions without you needing to anything!** And you can use them to compare to your ...

Comment: <continued> local Jupyter where you work on installing and getting them to work.

Comment: Sorry, I should have tested first. Right now for itkwidgets in JupyterLab via the itkwidgets launch, I see `ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when I try `from itkwidgets import view`. Presumably that may be able to be fixed by updating configuration file(s). But I wanted to point out it doesn't work to come out all set up. One of use should file an issue perhaps pointing this out? The upshot is that it won't work right now in a MyBinder session launched that way, sadly.